# How to filter the xcodebuild command line output?

Tags: xcode, build-process, console, build-automation, xcodebuild

Running `xcodebuild` from the console will bring you very verbose output and I wasn't able to locate any options for limit its output in order to display only warnings and errors.

I'm looking for a way to capture the `xcodebuild` output and filter it. It would prefer a Python solution that will work with pipes but I'm open to other approaches as long they are command line based solutions.

Are any tools that are already able to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To only see the error output messages, redirect the standard output to /dev/null (a special file that works as a black hole) like this:

```
xcodebuild > /dev/null
```

If you want to capture the error output into a file, you can do:

```
xcodebuild 2> ./build_errors.log
```

Comment: If you try this on a build server, make sure the build agent has permissions to that path. What happened to me is that build kept going and timed out, without warning about the permissions issue in GitLab.

Answer (score 121):

Use `xcodebuild -quiet`.

According to the xcodebuild man page:

> -quiet : Do not print any output except for warnings and errors.

Bonus: No other tools necessary! (Although I also like `xcodebuild | xcpretty`)

I build with Travis CI, which complains after 4 MB of logs. This argument solved the problem.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, works only for Xcode 8+. For previous Xcodes see answer by @rosejn.

Answer (score 50):

There’s a Ruby gem called [`xcpretty`](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty).

It filters the output of `xcodebuild` and also provides different formatters and coloring.

*UPDATE*: As Mike Hardy correctly states in the comments to this answer, `xcpretty` is no longer maintained.

Comment: please vote up this answer, this tool is awesome and solve the problem much better than grep

Comment: This tools is fantastic! Why I haven't discovered it before?!

Comment: xcpretty is a useful tool to be used in conjunction with xcodebuild.

Comment: @Koraktor- Can I use it with ANT exec task (for xcodebuild) as an argument?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Provably, but I'm not an Ant user.

Comment: Ok. Let's keep aside the ANT thing. How to use this for command line builds via xcodebuild archive?

Comment: XCPretty is really cool but sometimes crashes with error "NON-ASCII symbol".

Comment: xcpretty is abandoned and no longer maintained. `-quiet` is the way

Comment: @MikeHardy [`xcbeautify`](https://github.com/tuist/xcbeautify) might be what you want.

Comment: indeed! Even xcbeautify was abandoned temporarily but now it has new maintainer(s) and is what I am currently using. It looks like it should keep working for a while

Answer (score 36):

This isn't sufficient for me.  Piping to /dev/null will just show you that a build failed, but you don't see the reason(s) why.  Ideally we could see just the errors and/or warnings without all of the successful compiler commands.

This basically does the job:

```
xcodebuild | grep -A 5 error:
```

Comment: or  `egrep '^(/.+:[0-9+:[0-9]+:.(error|warning):|fatal|===)' -`  to also get lines saying what xcodebuild is about to do.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

`-quiet` is the best way to do it at now.

Comment: quiet is too quiet for me. xcpretty is dead. xcbeautify is the new tool that does this wonderfully and is well-maintained

Answer (score 6):

There’s a Swift command line tool https://github.com/thii/xcbeautify that can also format xcodebuild output.

Comment: Nice! Was looking for something since xcpretty was abandoned. xcbeautify is great, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I love `xcpretty` for looking at as a human, but I had a need to find build errors in an automated setting for propagation elsewhere, and I wanted to be sure I captured just the relevant information. The following sed command serves that purpose:

```
xcodebuild | sed -nE '/error:/,/^[[:digit:]] errors? generated/ p'
```

Output:

```
main.c:16:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'
    x = 5;
    ^
main.c:17:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'
    y = 3;
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am building an expo project and there are a lot of warnings that come from libraries which I don't want to see. I was able to filter out the warnings with this command.

```sh
set -o pipefail \
&& xcodebuild build -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme app \
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" \
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \
CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO \
| xcpretty \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "[-W" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "*" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "^" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F ";" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -e "^$" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "@" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F ")" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "/" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "}" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "{" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "\\" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F "#" \
| grep --line-buffered -v -F ","
```

I'll admit it's a little sloppy but I couldn't get any of the other solutions to work. The `-quiet` option still printed hundreds of warnings I had no ability to resolve.

What is strange is that when I compile on the command line on the build machine I wasn't getting the warnings but when I compiled in my CI build I would get the warnings. Very annoying. I wish apple would provide a way to silence warnings for xcodebuild

Comment: when you have warnings you don't like in pods you don't control (like libevent, in react-native / expo builds), you want to actually disable them since they are basically out of scope for you. You can do that in a podfile postinstall, like this https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-authentication-example/blob/f21b0bba63e299535e2d35a41d98cb3d3b45075e/template/ios/Podfile#L33

Answer (score 0):

I have been bitten by `xcpretty` swallowing way too much information in a CI environment, making it pretty hard to debug the error. `-quiet` hides output in a way that's a bit too aggressive, so I put together this one-liner and called it [`xcquiet.sh`](https://gist.github.com/andersonvom/0b2df86da2a246b77884f398f4a11b40). It only hides specific lines, while preserving enough of the original output and not swallowing any other unexpected log entries.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove warnings use

```
xcodebuild <command> | sed -e '/warning:/,/\^/d'
```

if you want to suppress warnings while using `xcpretty` try this

```
xcodebuild <command> \
    | sed -e '/warning:/,/\^/d' \
    | xcpretty -s
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [xcbeautify](https://github.com/tuist/xcbeautify) with the `quiet` (warnings and errors) or `quieter` (only errors) options.

Example from their site, adapted to warnings and errors:

```bash
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild [flags] | xcbeautify --quiet
```

Answer (score -1):

We run detox build command and it threw too many logs in CI.
`-quite` parameter failed with hiding logs.

The best solution is to hide and save logs in file:

```
npx detox build -c ios &> detox_build.log
```