# Reduce how much xcodebuild writes to command-line

Tags: macos, command-line, xcodebuild

I have a simple script that runs xcodebuild for a C++ project. However it prints out a huge amount of output for each file compiled, 10-20 lines, which makes it impossible to read easily. Ideally I'd jut like to see a list of the files compiled, one per line.

I'm not a nix guy but it seems like nix command-line can do pretty much anything... is there a neat way to do this? xcodebuild itself doesn't seem to have any control options for verbosity.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out for this? I am running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question might help:

[How to filter the xcodebuild command line output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244637/how-to-filter-the-xcodebuild-command-line-output)

Basically, you can just pipe the output and search what you need to show with grep.