# Suppress xcodebuild output or make less verbose

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, teamcity, xcodebuild

I am building my app in teamcity with xcodebuild command line tools. I am looking for a way to suppress or make the output less verbose but still show errors or failures if they happen. The build log becomes very large and the browser has a hard time loading it.

Are there optional parameters I can pass in or a way to stream it to a log file?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. However You can make the log more readable with `xctool` or `xcpretty` - not sure the size is also changed. Probably, it is.

Comment: Used xctool, I like it. Thanks

Comment: It is possible, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244637/how-to-filter-the-xcodebuild-command-line-output

Answer (score 2):

If you use xcpretty https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty you will have something readable and less verbose, the size will be smaller. It's a great tool, especially if you have unit test. You can take a look to the github they show exemples.